# Rails 5 Server Issues (Windows 10)

Tags: permissions, rubygems, windows-10, warnings, ruby-on-rails-5

Newbie to Ruby on Rails here, I just did a fresh install of Ruby & Rails on Windows 10 (Bash on Ubuntu shell). I seems to having issues on starting the Rails server. Already checked the other threads on the issue, but everyone else is using OSX. :( Hope someone can help!

When running rails s,

```
root@TEAMROCKETHQ:~/newapp# rails s
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:40: warning: Insecure world writable dir /root/.rbenv/versions in PATH, mode 040777
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.8.0 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

For the first line issue, I tried:

```
sudo chmod 775 /usr/local
```

it seems it didn't do anything. Maybe I'm reading the error wrong, but I don't know... When I go to localhost:3000, it returns this error:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.8.0 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-03-09 23:17:26 -0600: Read error: #<Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - getsockopt(2)>
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.0/lib/puma/server.rb:124:in `getsockopt'
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.0/lib/puma/server.rb:124:in `closed_socket?'
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.0/lib/puma/server.rb:563:in `handle_request'
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.0/lib/puma/server.rb:425:in `process_client'
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.0/lib/puma/server.rb:289:in `block in run'
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Webpage:

The **localhost** page isn't working

**localhost** is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `puma 3.8.0`.

Put `gem 'puma', '3.7.1'` in your gem file, and `bundle install` again.

And `gem uninstall puma` at version `3.8.0`, wait until there is a fix.

Comment: Fixed my original problem, but another problem arose.

Comment: There are a couple of issues around after ~>3.8.0 update. Ref for this question: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1240, @EverywhereSean